# Probability, tunnelling and transmission ratio

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-tunneling

This question is about tunnelling. It is from Physics for the IB diploma book.

The question introduces this graphWhere it is said the graph does not take reflected electrons into account and that the values on the vertical axis are arbitrary.

The author asks about the width of the barrier then asks about the ratio of the kinetic energy of electrons after tunnelling to the kinetic energy before tunnelling. Those are found to be respectively w=1.5 X 10^-10 m. However, the ratio is 1 since the deBroglie wavelength is the same before and after.

After this the author asks about the fraction of the incident electrons that tunnel through the barrier. The way I thought about this is use probability of transmitted electrons to those incident. That would be then p=1.3^2/2^2. But the author got (3/20)^2. Can someone explain the author's result? Thank you.[image]

Comment: How did you get *your* result? Note that the vertical axis is incorrectly labeled. The first 2 is probably a 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vertical axis is simply mislabeled.  The numbers from top to bottom should read 2, 1, -1, -2 (with 0 implied at the thicker horizontal line), instead of 2, 2, -1, -2.  So the peak of the wave on the right-hand side is only at 0.3, instead of 1.3.

You surely know that $0.3/2.0 = 3/20$, but I wonder if the author decided that counting the boxes on the graph paper would be easier.  The smaller peak is 3 boxes above the horizontal axis, while the larger peaks are 20 boxes above it.  Anyway, the result is the same.